# How do I return a list of enum elements for a generic enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am making a card game with a friend and I decided to make a card viewer, we input the all of card details into a text document and my program reads each card in, line by line.

Different types of card have different properties, all properties are represented in some type of enum.

I have some code which converts lists of strings into lists of enum properties. Example Enums:

```
public enum Race{
ELVES, HUMANS, DWARFS
} 

public enum Rarity{
COMMON, UNCOMMON, RARE
}
```

Assuming a card can have multiple Races and multiple rarities I want to make a method that can take a list of strings and a type of enum and return a list of enum values, e.g.

```
// Take in an array of strings and a type of Enum value to convert them to
public <Type extends Enum<Type>> Type[] getValues(String[] strings){

// Make an array to hold the enum values
Type[] values = new Type[strings.length];

// For each string, convert it into an enum value and add it to the array
for (int i = 0; i < strings.lenght; i++)
    values[i] = Type.valueOf(strings[i]);

return values;
}
```

I know this method doesn't work, but I hope it portrays at least what I am trying to do, I'd like a method to which I can send any list of strings and it will convert them into a list of EnumValues, e.g. convert the strings {"ELVES", HUMANS"} to the relevant Race values {ELVES, HUMANS}.

You might ask why I don't just make separate methods like

```
convertRaceStings(String[] strings){//method workings here}
convertRarityStings(String[] strings){//method workings here}
```

unfortunately the two enums used here are simple examples, there are a lot more enums which would each require another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with arrays is somewhat annoying in generic code.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E extends Enum<E>> E[] getValues(Class<E> clazz, String[] strings) {
  E[] result = (E[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, strings.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = Enum.valueOf(clazz, strings[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 4):

You should use an EnumSet instead of an array of enums. It is more memory efficient.
As a bonus you won't have to mess with generics arrays.

Your method will then look like:

```
private static <T extends Enum<T>> EnumSet<T> createEnumSet(Class<T> clazz, String... values) {
    EnumSet<T> set = EnumSet.noneOf(clazz);
    for(String value : values) {
        set.add(Enum.valueOf(clazz, value));
    }
    return set;
}
```

Well except if you need to have multiple instance of the same enum.

Usage:

```
final EnumSet<Race> races = createEnumSet(Race.class, "HUMANS", "DWARFS");
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you passed the enum type as well - that would enable you to use the [`Enum#valueOf` static method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(get("ELVES", Race.class));
    System.out.println(get("COMMON", Rarity.class));
}

public static <T extends Enum<T>> T get(String value, Class<T> clazz) {
    return Enum.valueOf(clazz, value);
}

public static enum Race {

    ELVES, HUMANS, DWARFS
}

public static enum Rarity {

    COMMON, UNCOMMON, RARE
}
```

If you don't want to pass the enum class as a second argument, you will need to maintain a mapping somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Enums in Java are very powerful. Since enumerations are constant and cannot be dynamically added, you could do something like this:

```
public enum Race {
    ELVES, HUMANS, DWARFS;

    public static Race getValue(String name) {
        switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
            case "evles": return EVLES;
            case "humans": return HUMANS;
            case "dwarfs": return DWARFS;
            default: throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you're using Java 7, but if not, replace the switch with else-if statements.

Comment: It's a bad idea to make that an instance method.